# Maven WAR file does not exclude test classes

Tags: maven, war

I'm trying to exclude test classes from my final WAR file with Maven.
Normally it should be done by default if my tests are in src/test/java but it is not doing it in my case.
Test classes are compiled in folder WEB-INF\test-classes\
So I added following plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>**/test-classes/*.class</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

But even with that, my test classes are still included in the .war file at the end
Does anyone have a workaround or can explain me what I'm missing ?
Thanks

**UPDATE : plugins that i use in my pom.xml**

```
         <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- fix clean issue where duplicated entries of pom are created-->
                    <!--https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405915-->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                          <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                              <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                              <includes>
                                <include>**/pom.properties</include>
                                <include>**/pom.xml</include>
                              </includes>
                            </fileset>
                          </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                <pluginExecutions>
                                    <pluginExecution>
                                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>bind</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <versionRange>[1.2.6,)</versionRange>
                                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <action>
                                            <execute>
                                                <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                            </execute>
                                        </action>
                                    </pluginExecution>


                                    <pluginExecution>
                                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>enhance</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <versionRange>[2.2.2,)</versionRange>
                                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <action>
                                            <execute>
                                                <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                            </execute>
                                        </action>
                                    </pluginExecution>

                                    <pluginExecution>
                                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>run</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <versionRange>[1.8,)</versionRange>
                                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <action>
                                            <execute>
                                                <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                            </execute>
                                        </action>
                                    </pluginExecution>
                                </pluginExecutions>
                                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>

            <plugins>  

                <!-- toolchain plugin to use specific JDK 
                 <plugins>
                      <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                          <execution>
                            <goals>
                              <goal>toolchain</goal>
                            </goals>
                          </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                          <toolchains>
                            <jdk>
                              <version>1.8</version>
                              <vendor>ibm</vendor>
                            </jdk>
                          </toolchains>
                        </configuration>
                      </plugin>
                    </plugins>
        -->

                  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.6</source>
                      <target>1.6</target>
                  <!--     <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>-->
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>


                <!-- OPENJPA -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>com/dsv/express/persistence/domain/*.class</includes>
                        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
                        <persistenceXmlFile>${project.basedir}${persistenceXmlFile-Path}</persistenceXmlFile>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enhancer</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enhance</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>


        </plugins>
```

Comment: Please show the full pom file cause Test Classes will never being packaged into a jar/war etc. by default which means the project must be doing something weird...

Comment: @TCH seems like, you defined your own test files.. why don't you follow the  maven convention ?  https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html. following already existing conventions,  makes your life easy

Comment: @khmarbaise There is absolutely nothing in the pom.xml which precise to package tests  in .war file.I updated my post with all the plugins I'm using in pom.xml

Comment: @André I'm already following these conventions that's why it is really weird...

Comment: You are not going the conventions cause defining clean plugin to delete things...furthermore a packagingExcludes which usually is not needed...with out the full pom it's hard to say what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well problem was I used maven `package` goal which did not include integration test. Running `mvn install` solved my problem ! Thanks